# The best way to store URL constants

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build an `Android` application. I've about 31 `URL`s. Currently I am storing the URL Strings as Constants in a class named `UrlRes` so that I can call `UrlRes.SIGN_UP_URL` or `UrlRes.PRODUCT_ADD_URL`. Is this a right approach? Should I store each `URL` on specific models ? example `PRODUCT_ADD_URL` in `Product` model. I think it'll be more meaningful when I call `Product.PRODUCT_ADD_URL`.

Comment: No. Don't put in `string.xml`. It's not for URLs. This is quite opinion based, either way will be suitable. While `Product.PRODUCT_ADD_URL` might be more meaningful (as `Product.ADD_URL` to remove redundance), but having all the URLs in a single place would be more easy to handle. No need to wonder which class contained the constant.

Comment: Use can use the `StringResources` too. In `strings.xml` or you can also create a new resource files such as `url.xml` and you can keep them. And you can use it like `getString(R.string.url_one);`

Comment: If it will only ever be an android app then use the resource system provided. If, however, you see this being offered elsewhere and having it in a java class is more appropriate there then do that. At which point to follow other patterns it may also be best to do it at model level. IMHO.

Comment: I think storing all the urls  in `Resources` is little much expensive . as @Kayaman said,If i store it in a class i can easily access it and I guess  `string.xml` is used for multi-language support, isn't ? am really confused.

Comment: I haven't heard that. That doesn't mean it's wrong. The system is set up to manage that stuff for you. I can't see why you wouldn't use it. They're constants. Every constant string in my my apps are int xmls. I also understand the argument they aren't technically strings. It's all opinion based in my opinion ;)

Comment: It's true that `string.xml` is primarly used for i8n. I would avoid sticking URL constants in there, since URLs are not strings and it's highly unlikely that language would affect your URLs. I'd recommend a single place of storing them, even if you were to abuse `strings.xml`.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

In android's implementation each [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) provides some contract classes with the uris and fields of each entity. Each contract contains static inner classes or interfaces for the different parts of the ContentProvider it belongs to.
For instance the [UserDictionary](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/provider/UserDictionary.java) contains Words and the [Contacts](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/provider/Contacts.java) contract contains Settings, Groups and some helper methods.

I would prefer using the `Product.PRODUCT_ADD_URL` strategy because if more links will be added in the future it's much clearer for you or other developers working on your app to understand this approach.

Answer (score -2):

String resources are used primarily for layouts and views so storing URLs in `strings.xml` is not considered best practice. You may instead want to store it in a class and making URL as `public final static`.

Comment: There's absolutely no need to use a singleton. He already has a perfectly fine way of storing the constants in a class.

Comment: String resources are not only used for layout and views, what about i18n ?